# setcookie is working on localhost not working on server hosting

Tags: php

Hello i have a php base website everything is working but i try alot i cant solve one problem in code i am using cookie code below:

```
<?php  

setcookie("adm_userid",$useridd,time()+3600);
$userid=$_COOKIE["adm_userid"];

 ?>
ajaxwin=dhtmlwindow.open("ajaxbox", "ajax", "editPCriteria.php?userID=<?php echo $userid; ?>", "Edit Machine Details & Price Criteria" ,"width=550px,height=460px,left=350px,top=50px,scrolling=1")
ajaxwin.onclose=function(){return window.confirm("Are you sure to close")} 
}
</script>
```

Its working on localhost and some other server hosting accounts aswell. but own domain this is not working. when i am in any user profile page and when click on Edit Price Criteria i can put text box fields to enter into Database. but on hosting values are not updating and if there is value in database table not echo also

Please help me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to set the folder for storing the cookie, try something like this:

```
setcookie("adm_userid",$useridd,time()+3600, "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: i am using below code now its not working still
<?php  

setcookie("adm_userid",$useridd,time()+3600, "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$userid=$_COOKIE["adm_userid"];

 ?>

Comment: not sure, if it works in your local environment but not in the server, it means the code is fine but the implementation or security is messing with it. You should enable php debug information and look for warnings and errors, but I think the problem is related to the access to the folder where php tries to save the session information.